# How can I load all dependencies from an AssetBundle automatically?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I'm currently using Unity 5.3.4, and it's being kinda hard for me to get around using the Asset Bundles, and we really need to use them at our project. My main difficulty right now is that you can't make a bundle with it a scene and its dependant objects, alright, I have a main bundle, which is "cena1" and a bundle of its objects "objcena1", looking at the cena1 manifest, I can see that there is a "Dependencies:" field, followed by the path where my objcena1 bundle is. But, for some reason, when I load the scene from "cena1", all objects are missing. How can I solve this? Thanks!

Quick Edit: the asset bundles are in different folders in my computer, just for testing.

Another Edit for the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using AssetBundles;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string sceneAssetBundle;
    public string sceneName;
    public string sName;
    public string bName;
    public string BundleURL;
    public string AssetName;
    public int version;

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine (DownloadAndCache());
    }

    IEnumerator DownloadAndCache (){
        // Wait for the Caching system to be ready
        while (!Caching.ready)
            yield return null;

        // Load the AssetBundle file from Cache if it exists with the same version or download and store it in the cache
        using(WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (BundleURL, version)){
            yield return www;
            if (www.error != null)
                throw new Exception("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
            AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
            if (AssetName == "")
                ;
            else
                StartCoroutine (Initialize ());
                StartCoroutine(InitializeLevelAsync(sceneName,true));
            // Unload the AssetBundles compressed contents to conserve memory
            bundle.Unload(false);

        } // memory is freed from the web stream (www.Dispose() gets called implicitly)
    }

    IEnumerator Start1() {
        using(WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (BundleURL, version)){
            yield return www;
            if (www.error != null)
                throw new Exception("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
            AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
            if (AssetName == ""){
                Instantiate(bundle.mainAsset);

            }
        }

        yield return StartCoroutine(Initialize() );

        // Load level.
        yield return StartCoroutine(InitializeLevelAsync (sceneName, true) );
    }

    public void getScene(string sName){
        sceneName = sName;
    }

    public void getBundle(string bName){
        sceneAssetBundle = bName;
    }

    // Initialize the downloading url and AssetBundleManifest object.
    public IEnumerator Initialize(){


        // Don't destroy this gameObject as we depend on it to run the loading script.
        //DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        // With this code, when in-editor or using a development builds: Always use the AssetBundle Server
        // (This is very dependent on the production workflow of the project. 
        //  Another approach would be to make this configurable in the standalone player.)
        #if DEVELOPMENT_BUILD || UNITY_EDITOR
        AssetBundleManager.SetDevelopmentAssetBundleServer ();
        #else
        // Use the following code if AssetBundles are embedded in the project for example via StreamingAssets folder etc:
        AssetBundleManager.SetSourceAssetBundleURL(Application.dataPath + "/");
        // Or customize the URL based on your deployment or configuration
        AssetBundleManager.SetSourceAssetBundleURL("http://www.MyWebsite/MyAssetBundles");
        #endif

        // Initialize AssetBundleManifest which loads the AssetBundleManifest object.
        var request = AssetBundleManager.Initialize();

        if (request != null)
            yield return StartCoroutine(request);
    }

    public IEnumerator InitializeLevelAsync (string levelName, bool isAdditive)
    {
        // This is simply to get the elapsed time for this phase of AssetLoading.
        float startTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

        // Load level from assetBundle.
        AssetBundleLoadOperation request = AssetBundleManager.LoadLevelAsync(sceneAssetBundle, levelName, isAdditive);
        if (request == null)
            yield break;
        yield return StartCoroutine(request);


        // Calculate and display the elapsed time.
        float elapsedTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - startTime;
        Debug.Log("Finished loading scene " + levelName + " in " + elapsedTime + " seconds" );
    }
}
```

Edit 13/05: Trying another code, this time, it doesn't even loads the scene it is supposed to, it just says the thing I wanna instantiate is null. I mean, assetBundles are giving me a hell of a headache, thought it would be easier to implement. Both of these codes are showed up as a tutorial on unity's website, and well, I've been trying them for almost a week with no results. There are no assets that should be present in the assetbundle in the assets folder of the project except for the script, according to the assetbundles logic, they should contain all the assets, right? Well, here's the new code, which doesn't works either.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour {
    public string BundleURL;
    public string AssetName;
    public int version;

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine (DownloadAndCache());
    }

    IEnumerator DownloadAndCache (){
        // Wait for the Caching system to be ready
        while (!Caching.ready)
            yield return null;

        // Load the AssetBundle file from Cache if it exists with the same version or download and store it in the cache
        using(WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (BundleURL, version)){
            yield return www;
            if (www.error != null)
                throw new Exception("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
            AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
            if (AssetName == "")
                Instantiate(bundle.mainAsset);
            else
                Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset(AssetName));
            // Unload the AssetBundles compressed contents to conserve memory
            bundle.Unload(false);

        } // memory is freed from the web stream (www.Dispose() gets called implicitly)
    }
}
```

Comment: can u include the code where you load it?  (just click "Edit" to do so.  be sure to use the "code format" button on code..)

Comment: added the code, it's the average load scenes code from the unity manager samples btw, i just added a function to download the scenes (i use a local url in my computer for testing) and another one to get the name of the scenes from the buttons, also, this project does not includes the assets, i thought i wouldn't need them since, you know, i already build the asset bundles

Comment: sorry don't have time to look at all code just now but, could it be this simple mistake?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37164073/294884  At your line 36+37 you seem to be not waiting where you should wait, no?

Comment: hmmmm, i'm going to try that, and don't worry, thank you for your time!

Comment: again i'm not sure exactly where, but it is possible that's the problem "somewhere".  suggest strongly add **Debug.Log** everywhere !! xx

Comment: Dependencies is not the problem as this is supported in Unity. Just like Joe said, replace your `StartCoroutine(Initialize());
            StartCoroutine(InitializeLevelAsync(sceneName, true));`  with `yield return StartCoroutine(Initialize());
            yield return StartCoroutine(InitializeLevelAsync(sceneName, true));`.

Comment: weird, it still doesn't loads the dependant asset bundle, which is "objcena1", and again, it is still specified in the manifest, but anyways, I'll keep poking around the code, thank you guys for your help :D

Comment: Well, it works just fine as long as I have the assets referenced by the dependant asset bundle in the assets folder, I don't understand why I need that since the asset bundle will be created